# Forwarding default URL to specific URI in HAProxy

Tags: haproxy

I am new to HAProxy. I tried to configure the HAProxy to forward the URL to specific URI.
For example, my URL is https://www.example.com and I want to forward it to https://www.example.com/aks/

My HAProxy configurations is :

```
frontend Listen443
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/example.com-wildcard.pem

    acl web_url          path_beg   /aks 
    use_backend WEB      if web_url

    default_backend WEB

# Send traffic to the web layer on port 8080

backend WEB


    mode http

    balance roundrobin

    option httpclose

    cookie SERVERIDWEB insert indirect nocache secure

    option forwardfor

    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]

    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }

    server app-1 app1.example.com:8080 check cookie app1web

    server app-2 app2.example.com:8080 check cookie app2web

    server app-3 app3.example.com:8080 check cookie app3web
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `acl is_root path -i /` which would match to an empty context (https://www.example.com/)
Then redirect all matching sessions to https://www.example.com/aks 
After which match the rule to web_url

i.e:

```
acl is_root path -i  /
acl is_domain hdr(host) -i www.example.com
redirect code 301 location https://www.example.com/aks if is_domain is_root
acl web_url path_beg /aks
use_backend WEB if web_url
```

Comment: Actually,` is_root -i /` doesn't work because it appears, even though not shown in the browser bar, there is something there perhaps  /HTTP1.1